# can we give required function for name attribute

Tags: javascript, php, required

Here I am having radio button and checkbox button and i want to give required function, so that i gave my code like this

```js
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        
        $cbx_group = $("input:radio[name='occupation_status[]']");
        $cbx_group1 = $("input:checkbox[name='occupation_status[]']");
        
        if(($cbx_group.not(":checked"))&&($cbx_group1.not(":checked"))){

          document.getElementByName("occupation_status").required = true;
        } else{
        
           $cbx_group.prop('required', false);
           $cbx_group1.prop('required', false);
        }
     });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Occupation status:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <label class="radio-inline formui-radio option">
      <input type="radio"  name="occupation_status[]" id="occupation_status1" value="self">
      Self </label>
    <label class="radio-inline formui-radio option">
      <input type="radio" name="occupation_status[]" id="occupation_status2" value="employed">
      Employed </label>
       <span>
  <label class="checkbox-inline form-checkbox option" style=" width: 113px;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="occupation_status[]" id="occupation_status3" value="Night Shift"/>Night Shift
  </label>
  </span>
  <label class="radio-inline formui-radio option">
      <input type="radio" name="occupation_status[]" id="occupation_status4" value="Retired">
      Retired </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

when both the checkbox and the radio button is not checked it should show  at least one to be checked and if any radio button or checkbox button is checked it should perform false condition

Comment: how is it related to angularjs?

Comment: sorry angular js came by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this snippet:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
    var radio_group = $('input[type="radio"][name="occupation_status[]"]');
    var cbx_group = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="occupation_status[]"]');
    
    changeRequiredStatus();
    
    $('[name="occupation_status[]"]').change(function(){
      changeRequiredStatus();
    });
    
    function changeRequiredStatus(){
        if(!radio_group.is(":checked")&&!cbx_group.is(":checked")){
            $('[name="occupation_status[]"]').prop('required',true);
        }
        else{
            $('[name="occupation_status[]"]').prop('required',false);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Occupation status:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <label class="radio-inline formui-radio option">
      <input type="radio"  name="occupation_status[]" id="occupation_status1" value="self">
      Self </label>
    <label class="radio-inline formui-radio option">
      <input type="radio" name="occupation_status[]" id="occupation_status2" value="employed">
      Employed </label>
       <span>
  <label class="checkbox-inline form-checkbox option" style=" width: 113px;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="occupation_status[]" id="occupation_status3" value="Night Shift"/>Night Shift
  </label>
  </span>
  <label class="radio-inline formui-radio option">
      <input type="radio" name="occupation_status[]" id="occupation_status4" value="Retired">
      Retired </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can we give if both radio button and checkbox button have different values

Comment: @user_777 what do you mean by have different values ?

Comment: i mean if both have different names

Comment: @user_777 just change the selectors, for example: `var radio_group = $('input[type="radio"][name="new_name[]"]');` and also you need to set its property by using the new name `$('[name="new_name[]"]').prop('required',true);` thats what are asking about ?